# Secure wordpress_logged_in cookie

Tags: cookies

I have to make sure, that the Wordpress cookie set after successful log in, "wordpress_logged_in_[salt-sth]" is set to be available for secure connections only.

It looks like that it´s a filter used in pluggable.php, line 653

$secure_logged_in_cookie = apply_filters('secure_logged_in_cookie', false, $user_id, $secure);

How can I set it to secure, WITHOUT modifiyng the wordpress core files?
If I modify the core (set to true) - it´s not possible to logout anymore...

Thank U!

Comment: In addition to the question above: Cookie is secure now, but the user is logged out automatically directly after loggin in. How can I prevent this? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of a filter is that you can change a value *without* modifying core WP files.  The filter you list:

```
$secure_logged_in_cookie = apply_filters('secure_logged_in_cookie', false, $user_id, $secure);
```

Passes in three values. You just need to build a function that *accepts* those three values and returns `true` (or just returns `true` by default.

This function, for example, merely returns true for whatever value is passed in to that filter:

```
add_filter( 'secure_logged_in_cookie', '__return_true' );
```

Comment: Great, thx for your fast reply - I understand and will try this!

Comment: Thank you! I was digging around in pluggable.php to see where the cookies were getting set and found the `apply_filter` call. This is perfect, and today I learned about WP's `__return_true` function